# Stage and classes

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new to AS3 and am trying to lean its OOP ways. What I am having problems with is understanding how to access the stage with separate classes.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
package game{
import flash.display.*;

public class Main extends MovieClip{

    function Main(){
        var player = new Player();
        var playerBullets = new playerBullet();
        addChild(player.players);
    }

}

package game{
import flash.display.*;

public class Bullet extends Main // also tried with MovieClip and Sprite{

    function Bullet(){
        // empty
    }


    function blah(){
        var someSprite = new someSprite();

        Main.addChild(someSprite);
        stage.addChild(someSprite);
        root.addChild(someSprite);


    }
}
}
```

I have Omitted another class which calls the blah method as I feel it is not relevant.

Basically what I want to know is how to add things to the stage in classes as it lookes like I am missing something crucial.

****EDIT TO INCLUDE ERROR****

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at game::Bullet/blah()
    at game::Player/fire()

Comment: Main is my class linked to the .fla

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't necessarily be extending main to create something like a bullet class, this can be it's own class that extends Sprite or MovieClip. The stage object is considered a global object, as it is a singleton (except in the case of Adobe AIR where you can have one stage per NativeWindow that you spawn). So any object that extends DisplayObject or has DisplayObject in it's inheritance chain will by default have a reference to the stage via a getter, which is populated automatically when a displayObject is added to the display list. This can happen by either adding a clip directly to the root stage object or by adding a clip as a child of another clip, that eventually connects to the stage. For example:

```
var clip1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

stage.addChild(clip1); //Clip 1 can now access the stage reference internally.

ver clip2:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); //Right now, clip2 cannot access the stage reference interally.

clip1.addChild(clip2); //Now clip2 can access the internal stage reference because it has been connected to the display list through clip1.
```

The other mistake people make is accessing stage within a DisplayObject typed class (such as your Main class) without first ensuring that the object itself has been added to the stage. You do this by listening for the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event within the constructor of the class, like so:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip{

    function Main(){
        if(stage){
            //The stage reference is present, so we're already added to the stage
            init();
        }else{
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        var player = new Player();
        var playerBullets = new playerBullet();
        addChild(player.players);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null)
    {
         trace("Added to stage, the stage reference is now populated and stage can be accessed");
    }

}
```

This could be the problem you're having, but it's hard to say since you have not specified any errors. However, this is likely an issue or will be for you, since it's quite common. Inside the init() method you can then set a flag so that when external classes call your Main.blah() method, you can ensure that the stage reference exists before attempting to add something to the stage. Take note however that within your Main class when you simply say:

addChild(someChild);

or

this.addChild(someChild);

you're not adding that child to the stage, but rather to the Main object, which is a MovieClip or Sprite based object that is itself attached to the stage automatically when you set it as the Document class. Hope this info helps.

**Update**
To explain the display list a little more:

Think of all your movieclips as dishes, and the stage as the table. You can only access the table from the dish, if the dish is placed directly on the table, or if a dish is stacked on top of another dish that touches the table. If you have 10 plates stacked on top of each other, they all touch the table eventually, via their connection to each other. This is essentially a visualization of the flash display list. The way you put dishes on the table is by using addChild(dish). If you have not placed an object somewhere on the table, and try to access the table from that object, you're going to fail. You're getting the "access to undefined" error because you're calling the "blah()" method, which accesses the stage (table) before the bullet (dish) has been added to the stage (table). So you must first either directly add the bullet to the stage, or add it to another object that has already been added to the stage. Change your code like so:

```
var myBullet:Bullet = new Bullet();
stage.addChild(myBullet);
//Or, if this class, assuming it's the player class, has already been added to the stage, just do this:
this.addChild(myBullet);
myBullet.blah();
```

Even so, you should still have some error checking within your "blah" method to ensure that the stage is available:

```
  function blah(){
        var someSprite = new someSprite();
        if(stage){
            Main.addChild(someSprite);
            stage.addChild(someSprite);
            root.addChild(someSprite);
        }else{
            trace("error, stage not present");
        }
    }
```

However you should also note that by adding this child to Main, then stage, then root all in sequence, this does not duplicate the someSprite object. When you add a display object to a new parent object, the object is automatically pulled from it's current parent and moved to the new one. So all this code will do is eventually add someSprite to root, which I believe will fail because root is not a display object, but rather a global reference mainly used to access global objects such as the stage and the Loader object used to load the SWF.

Comment: The error I receive is TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at game::Bullet/blah()
 at game::Player/fire()

I have tried to read your reply but I can't seem to understand what you mean with the first code block. If possible could you explain it in more layman's terms?

Comment: Updated my answer with an analogy of the display list + some more nfo.

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort you have put into explaining, very helpful!

Comment: Excellent explanation for the stage and display objects.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't ever be calling stage.addChild.  There should be only one child of the Stage, and that's the document class.

You make a MovieClip display on the screen by adding it to the stage's display list.

```
Stage
   + Main Timeline
       +Anything
       +Else
       +You
       +Want
```

So assuming that Main is your document class for the main timeline...

```
 // inside of Main's constructor...

 public function Main(){
   var anything:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
   var Else:TextField = new TextField();
   var you:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
   var want:Sprite = new Sprite();
   this.addChild(anything);
   this.addChild(Else);
   this.addChild(you);
   this.addChild(want);
 }
```

Then in order to add children even lower, for example if you want something to be a child of "Anything" such that you have....

```
Stage
   + Main Timeline
       +Anything
            +And
            +Everything
       +Else
       +You
       +Want




 public function Main(){
   var anything:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
   var Else:TextField = new TextField();
   var you:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
   var want:Sprite = new Sprite();

   this.addChild(anything);
   this.addChild(Else);
   this.addChild(you);
   this.addChild(want);

   var And:Sprite = new Sprite();
   var everything:Sprite = new Sprite();
   anything.addChild(And);
   anything.addChild(everything);
 }
```

EDIT: Ascension Systems asks why you should never add any display object directly as a child of the stage.  The simplest answer is that you can't ever guarantee that what you believe you're creating as a document class, or as a main timeline in fact actually is going to be used as such.  Your use of the stage may later preclude your swf from being loaded as a child of a larger application depending on what it is you've done, exactly.  Relying directly on the stage can mean that you're making some assumptions about the nature of the display list that may not hold in the future.  That's the way in which it breaks modularity (which is not the same as breaking oop).

Why add to the stage when you could just create your entire application as a MovieClip that is completely self-contained with no reliance on the concept of a "stage" beyond that which is required for learning world coordinates?  That way you can be much more modular in your design and you sacrifice nothing.

In some people's work this may be considered an edge case.  In my work this has happened both to me when I've created applications that I *thought* at the time were purely stand-alone that ended up being repurposed later to be a module, and also to swfs that other people created that were intended to be strictly stand-alone, but that I was then to integrate as a module into a larger application.  In all cases there were some nasty side effects to contend with.  That's where I learned not to rely too closely on the stage for much beyond world coordinates.

Comment: Would love to know the logic behind never adding anything to the stage. That is a completely unfounded and ridiculous rule. It's not anti-oop, in fact it's not against any rule anywhere ever.

Comment: Thanks I don't mean to be rude, it just appears as something that is more a personal preference of yours than an absolute. I'll watch for the edit. :)

Comment: It's acceptable, but possibly unwise, to add stuff directly to stage, alongside root. It goes in the "edge case" category where bugs may be more likely. e.g. `root.width` will no longer be equivalent to the width of your content. Makes it easier to mess up. And I'm not sure I trust adobe to get it right either.

Comment: @scriptocalypse: that's a much better reason than mine :) i guess using `stage` would be the equivalent of *not* using as2's `_lockroot`.

Comment: I understand your reasoning guys and it does make sense, my objection was that the statement was made as an explicit no-no without an explanation but the point is very valid, although I still disagree that it must be an absolute rule. You can still code things to work directly with the stage and utilize various built-in events to ensure everything is loaded and composed correctly and in order. However yes if you're building an application that uses external swfs or an application you may wish to load elsewhere later this definitely makes sense. +1

Comment: adding listeners to the stage is sometimes essential, for instance to catch bubbling events from different parts of your application, but I agree that `object.stage` should never be used as a target for adding display objects.

Comment: @shanethehat I do find that it's most useful to use the stage as a listener for KeyboardEvents.  I'd say though that even the bubbling event scenario is dicey.  For example, if your application is used as a module in a different swf, and that swf calls e.stopImmediatePropagation on an event that you're listening for before it reaches stage, you're out of luck.  These days I'm also not all that big on event bubbling as a matter of performance, though... Another thing to bear in mind if one is making a game (which if you have some classes like Bullet and Player is a likely scenario).

Answer (score 2):

Every display object has a property called `stage`, which is null until that object is added to the display tree.

When you are unsure if an object has been added to the stage, there is a listener you can employ for that purpose:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public function Main():void
    {
        if(stage) {
            init();
        } else {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        }
    }

    private function init(evt:Event = null):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        //object is now definitely on the display tree
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna take a wild stab in the dark here.

`stage` is  a property implemented something like so:

```
public function get stage():Stage {
    var s:DisplayObject = this;
    while(s.parent) s = s.parent;
    return s as Stage;
}
```

`root` is very similar but stops a level below stage (root is a child of stage).

These properties **only work** when the object you're calling them on **is on the stage somewhere**. Doesn't matter where, because the while loop will walk up the hierarchy to get to the stage node at the top. But if it's not on the stage, then `parent` will be null.

So if your movieclip is not on the stage, then its reference to `stage` will be null. Same goes for `root`.

I'm guessing that you're calling `blah` before the bullets are added to the stage? In which case your call `stage.addChild(someSprite)` will be a Null Reference error (stage is null).

So you either need to add the bullets to stage first, or you need to pass `stage` in as a parameter:

```
function blah(s:Stage){
    var someSprite = new someSprite();
    s.addChild(someSprite);
}
```

Comment: also I should add that you should *probably* be adding stuff to `root` rather than `stage`. Just in case.